# Texturing a pant

Tags: texturing, uv

I have downloaded a character and put pants on it.  I want to apply a texture on it but failed.  When I unwrap it it doesn't do it. How do I unwrap it properly to apply texture on it?

[image]

Comment: This is a very basic question. Try searching the Blender Stack Exchange or even searching Google.

Comment: UV maps aren't displayed in the UV/image editor if the Render Result is displayed in the UV/Image Editor. Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my unwrapped model appear in the UV Editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7889/why-doesnt-my-unwrapped-model-appear-in-the-uv-editor)

Comment: add a new image, then unwrap, it should work.